# Re-organizing Pandas DataFrame into more columns based on unique/repeated index values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reorganize my DataFrame in a certain way that creates new rows based on repeated index values.

```
import pandas as pd
values = [800.0, 400.0, 200.0, 100.0, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5, 0.0, 800.0, 400.0, 200.0, 100.0, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5, 0.0]
things = [3.0621, 1.5309, 0.75, 0.4001, 0.1978, 0.1031, 0.0509, 0.0031, 2.9066, 1.5859999999999999, 0.7945,0.3938, 0.2156, 0.1063, 0.0519, 0.0019]

tester = pd.DataFrame(data=things, index=values)
tester.columns = ['things']
tester.index.name = 'values'

In [3]: tester
Out[3]: 
        things
values        
800.0   3.0621
400.0   1.5309
200.0   0.7500
100.0   0.4001
50.0    0.1978
25.0    0.1031
12.5    0.0509
0.0     0.0031
800.0   2.9066
400.0   1.5860
200.0   0.7945
100.0   0.3938
50.0    0.2156
25.0    0.1063
12.5    0.0519
0.0     0.0019
```

I'd like re-design this as such:

```
       thing1  thing2
values
800.0  3.0621  2.9066
400.0  1.5309  1.5860
200.0  0.7500  0.7945
100.0  0.4001  0.3938
50.0   0.1978  0.2156
25.0   0.1031  0.1063
12.5   0.0509  0.0519
0.0    0.0031  0.0019
```

There's got to be some simple way to do this. Should I not be setting values as an index perhaps?

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I'd been searching for a while but couldn't find anything that specifically covers this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `cumcount` then `pivot`

```
tester=tester.assign(new=tester.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1)

s=tester.reset_index().pivot(index='values',columns='new',values='things').add_prefix('things').sort_index(ascending=False)
s
Out[43]: 
new     things1  things2
values                  
800.0    3.0621   2.9066
400.0    1.5309   1.5860
200.0    0.7500   0.7945
100.0    0.4001   0.3938
50.0     0.1978   0.2156
25.0     0.1031   0.1063
12.5     0.0509   0.0519
0.0      0.0031   0.0019
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The combination of these commands seems to elude me.

Comment: @NameyMcNamo yw :-)happy coding